# Wrong geometric output using Graphics when changing the order of objects

Tags: graphics, geometry

I have observed a strange behaviour with the following data for two lines and a point. Depending on the order in Graphics, Mathematica produces different geometric outputs. Does anybody know the reason for this?

```
x1 = {9.027522935779817, -3.0917431192660554};
x2 = {1, 18.21495327105389};
x3 = {2, 15.560747663572467};
x4 = {1, -6.116197183098593};
x5 = {2, -5.739436619718311};
one = Graphics[{Green, PointSize[0.03], InfiniteLine[{x4, x5}], 
   InfiniteLine[{x2, x3}], Point[x1]}]
two = Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Point[x1],  InfiniteLine[{x4, x5}], 
   InfiniteLine[{x2, x3}]}]
```

[image: output one]
[image: output two]

Comment: I think it has to do with how `Graphics` decides on the range based on the order of the objects to plot, similar to how `Show` uses the first plot to set some values. Try adding `Axes->True` to both cases. In the second case the range of the plot is much smaller because it is set relative to the point (I'm assuming). In the first case you are zoomed further out, so the point seems to lie on the intersection of the two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the axes command to the second plot:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[0.03], Point[{x1}], InfiniteLine[{x4, x5}], 
  InfiniteLine[{x2, x3}]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Watch the scale of the axes. Obviously `Graphics` chooses the region to plot so small that we see numerical errors of machine precision.

I think this should be reported to "support@wolfram.com"

Comment: Great, thank you... this explains everything :)